# Parse iOS SDK: callFunctionInBackground make duplicate requests after app comes back from background

Tags: ios, parse-platform

This happens quite frequently for our app recently. The iOS app saves an object or calls a cloud function, but the user leaves the app or loses internet connection before the request responses. So when the app comes back from the background or re-gain the connection, the request retries, which often creates a duplicate object.

The duplicate object can be created a long time after the first creation. I once saved a post object before I went into the subway station and lost internet connection. When I came out and connected to wifi again 20 minutes later, the second post with duplicate values were created.

What may be the best solution to handle this case? Is it possible to force the save completes when the app is in the background? And is it possible to cancel a request for save to avoid duplicate requests? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.parse.com/questions/unique-fields--2

Comment: @Jageen Hi, I do realized I could do it through server side using some unique id. But I really want to avoid making duplicate request. Uniqueness is less of an issue for me though. Currently it's quite often that user sends a post and leaves the app in the background for sometime (could be hours), when they come back, the save/request in the background is restarted and make a duplicate try. I would like to know if I can somehow stop this retry, or somehow let the request finishes when the app is in the background. Thanks.

Comment: I understand your problem now ... :), please update me if you fond any solution.